# Reflecting Across Serialized Object To Set PropertyChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a object that is created through deserialization of some XML.  I used Visual Studio's tool to generate the XSD from the vendor mockup XML. Then using the XSD tool I got classes from them.  I set the XSD tool so that it would make the generated classes be INotifyPropertyChanged.

Now I'm trying to display this object in a "tab" on my WPF application.  I want a "dirty" indicator whenever someone makes a change.  The issue is that this object, being generated classes from generated XSD is not the prettiest structure.  The display for this object is does not mimic its data structure.  I thought of creating display objects (not using MMVM ATM) and using those to bind my changes to and then persist those changes to the object as a data object.  I would essentially just throw out my current display to do this since I'm now just adding a check for if there were edits.

My thought is to reflect across the object and set the PropertyChanged event for every property I come across (walking through the graph of objects and properties).  My reflection fu is failing me and I'm also probably making some short-sighted mistakes.

Here is the code I've written thus far:

```
void SetupPropertyChanged(INotifyPropertyChanged component)
    {
        component.PropertyChanged += CAMConfig_PropertyChanged;

        Type componentType = component.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in componentType.GetProperties())
        {
            Type[] types =
                info.PropertyType.FindInterfaces((a, b) => { return a.ToString() == b.ToString(); }, typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged));

            bool isINotify = types.Contains(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged));


            if (isINotify)
                this.SetupPropertyChanged((INotifyPropertyChanged)info.GetValue(component, new object[] { }));
        }
    }
```

I think I'm running into Observable collection property type issues as its throwing an exception when I'm traversing my object.  It also just hit me that I don't know if this object structure would have circular references.

Can someone help me work out this code so that I can traverse the object graph.  Right now I'm not too concerned about the possibility of circular references, but if a solution presents itself that prevents that situation it would be very, very helpful!

Based on Karel's answer I've created this "helper" class:

```
    public static class NotifyPropertyChangedHelper
{
    public delegate void ChangeOccuredHandler(object sender);

    public static void SetupPropertyChanged(INotifyPropertyChanged component, ChangeOccuredHandler changedHandler)
    {
        SetupPropertyChanged(new List<object>(), component, changedHandler);
    }

    static void SetupPropertyChanged(IList<object> closed, INotifyPropertyChanged component, ChangeOccuredHandler changedHandler)
    {
        if (closed.Contains(component)) return; // event was already registered

        closed.Add(component); //adds the property that is to be processed

        //sets the property changed event if the property isn't a collection
        if (!(component is INotifyCollectionChanged))
            component.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    changedHandler(sender);
                };

        /*
         * If the component is an enumerable there are two steps. First check to see if it supports the INotifyCollectionChanged event.
         * If it supports it add and handler on to this object to support notification.  Next iterate through the collection of objects
         * to add hook up their PropertyChangedEvent.
         * 
         * If the component isn't a collection then iterate through its properties and attach the changed handler to the properties.
         */
        if (component is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
            if (component is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            {
                //((INotifyCollectionChanged)component).CollectionChanged += collectionHandler;
                ((INotifyCollectionChanged)component).CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        changedHandler(sender);
                    };
            }

            foreach (object obj in component as IEnumerable<object>)
            {
                if (obj is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                    SetupPropertyChanged(closed, (INotifyPropertyChanged)obj, changedHandler);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in component.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var propertyValue = info.GetValue(component, new object[] { });
                var inpc = propertyValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                if (inpc == null) continue;
                SetupPropertyChanged(closed, inpc, changedHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a list of properties (components) for which you've already registered the event and make your function recursive. And you can cast component to `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly.

```
void SetupPropertyChanged(IList<object> closed, INotifyPropertyChanged component)  
{
  if(closed.Contains(component)) return; // event was already registered

  closed.Add(component);

  component.PropertyChanged += CAMConfig_PropertyChanged;            
  foreach (PropertyInfo info in componentType.GetProperties())          
  {
    var propertyValue = info.GetValue(component, new object[] { });
    var inpc = propertyValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if(inpc == null) continue;
    this.SetupPropertyChanged(closed, inpc);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I like this solution for solving the graph issue and is cleaner for finding the interface I want, but I'm still getting this error: "Parameter count mismatch" when the componentType is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Are you reading the value of the property or the item from the collection? Write out the propertyInfo when exception is raised.

Comment: component = "Name = "ObservableCollection`1" FullName = "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1" and info.PropertyType = "Name = "ETLLoadDO" FullName = "AnalyticsManagementStudio.WPF.DisplayObjects.ETLLoadDO" (one of my objects that implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: My very bad! The method first registers the event for the observable collection, than step into itself and tries to do the same for the collection. But first property is indexer and in this case you need an index which is not supplied. So add condition 'if(component is INotifyCollectionChanged) return;' after adding component to list of closed objects.

Comment: I kinda caught that mistake.  I rewrote the method at the end of my question with what I think works.  Let me know if this seems acceptable.  The method just lets the consumer know that something has changed which is all I need in this case.